# ID attribute does not work but CLASS does?

Tags: jquery

I ran into this issue while practicing JQuery.

In the code below, I am trying to display an INPUT box when "Yes" is clicked, and hide it when "No" is clicked.

The ELSE IF statement within my JQuery syntax works perfectly when my INPUT tag has CLASS attributes.

But if I replace the CLASS attributes with ID attributes(ID="box1", ID="box2"), only the IF statement works but not the ELSE IF.(Please note that, I used appropriate Jquery selectors for ID and CLASS, so that may not be the issue).

Can someone please help me with this? The answer may be simple and obvious, but I am a beginner to JQuery, and this issue leaves me wondering. 
Thanks in advance!

Edited: Here's the problem code:

PS: I had been having issues posting this code on the comments, so I thought I would edit the original code snippet. Hope this helps!!!

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box2{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){           
        $("#box1").click(function(){
            var x = $(this).val();

            if (x == "Yes")
            {
                $("#box2").css("display", "inline");
            }
            else if (x == "No")
            {
                $("#box2").css("display", "none");
            }               
        }); 
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>  
<input type="radio" name="color" Id="box1" value="Yes"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="color" Id="box1" value="No"> No

<input type="text" size="10" name="exp" Id="box2">
```

Comment: It's better to show the code that *doesn't* work, so that we can see what's wrong. Showing *working* code isn't much help.

Answer (score 1):

As others answered, ID's must be unique; classes do not.  Also, it would be better than changing the css to use hide() and show().

Change to:

```
if (x == "Yes")  
{  
 $(".box2").show();  
}  
else if (x == "No")  
{  
  $(".box2").hide();  
}
```

should be easier to read your code.  Also, consider studying toggle().

Comment: I see the problem now...Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** using `id` http://jsfiddle.net/FsaJH/1/

Hope you are adding the correct ids correctly, and not duplicating them in DOM.

Please lemme know if I missed anything, This should help

**code**

```
 $(function(){           
        $("#box1, #box2").click(function(){  //<== chaining the ids here
            var x = $(this).val();  

            if (x == "Yes")  
            {  
                $(".box2").css("display", "inline");  
            }  
            else if (x == "No")  
            {  
                $(".box2").css("display", "none");  
            }                 
        });   
    });  ​
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Tats_innit. Within your IF block, did you mean to do #box2, in place of .box2. If so, then the code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess -- you don't actually show the code that has the problem; you show the *working* code -- is that you're using the same ID on multiple elements. IDs should be unique. That said, I'd write it like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="box1" value="Yes"> Yes  
<input type="radio" name="color" id="box2" value="No"> No  

<input type="text" size="10" name="exp" id="box3">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){           
    $("#box1, #box2").click(function(){  
        var x = $(this).val(); 
        $("#box3").css("display", x == "Yes" ? "inline" : "none");       
    });   
});
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WgLUt/